# Calculating time difference and summing based on another column

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have such a table that contains data like following

```
ReferenceNo                 CommentDate             StepName            Originator  StartTime
1   CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:20:07.000 Initiate Process    P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:20:07.000
1   CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:20:44.000 Finance Controller  P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:20:07.000
1   CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:21:52.000 Originator  P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:20:07.000
1   CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:23:26.000 Finance Controller  P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:20:07.000
1   CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:23:55.000 Finance Officer P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:20:07.000
2   CHQRCL/0089/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:43:48.000 Initiate Process    P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:43:48.000
2   CHQRCL/0089/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:43:59.000 Finance Controller  P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:43:48.000
2   CHQRCL/0089/2013/FEB    2013-02-25 15:44:11.000 Asset GM    P8Admin 2013-02-25 15:43:48.000
3   CHQRCL/0093/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:19:05.000 Initiate Process    P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:19:05.000
3   CHQRCL/0093/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:21:57.000 Finance Controller  P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:19:05.000
3   CHQRCL/0093/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:23:55.000 Asset GM    P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:19:05.000
3   CHQRCL/0093/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:24:09.000 CFO P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:19:05.000
3   CHQRCL/0093/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:24:19.000 CEO P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:19:05.000
3   CHQRCL/0093/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:24:40.000 Finance Officer P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:19:05.000
4   CHQRCL/0094/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 16:58:47.000 Initiate Process    P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:58:47.000
4   CHQRCL/0094/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 17:00:45.000 Finance Controller  P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:58:47.000
4   CHQRCL/0094/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 17:00:54.000 Asset GM    P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:58:47.000
4   CHQRCL/0094/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 17:04:48.000 CFO P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:58:47.000
4   CHQRCL/0094/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 17:05:06.000 CEO P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:58:47.000
4   CHQRCL/0094/2013/MAR    2013-03-06 17:05:35.000 Finance Officer P8Admin 2013-03-06 16:58:47.000
5   CHQRCL/0108/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 08:58:22.000 Initiate Process    Mohamed Ubaid   2013-03-10 08:58:22.000
5   CHQRCL/0108/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:06:23.000 Finance Controller  Mohamed Ubaid   2013-03-10 08:58:22.000
5   CHQRCL/0108/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:07:06.000 Finance Officer Mohamed Ubaid   2013-03-10 08:58:22.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000 Initiate Process    Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:32:34.000 Finance Controller  Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:33:22.000 Asset GM    Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:35:39.000 Originator  Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:36:06.000 Asset GM    Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:36:20.000 CFO Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:36:41.000 CEO Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
6   CHQRCL/0110/MAR/2013    2013-03-10 09:37:34.000 Finance Officer Allan C Fampulme    2013-03-10 09:26:10.000
```

First I want the time taken for each step (which is say for Finance Controller for reference no 1, it took 37 seconds) per reference number. The I want to calculate the average (taking the same Finance Controller step as example; it took 7 seconds for 1 refNo + 94 seconds once again in 1refNo + 11 seconds in 2refNo + and so on DIVIDED BY 6)

Comment: I had tried WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ReferenceNo ORDER BY CommentDate)As RowNum
    , *
    FROM FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory T
 --where  stepname != 'Initiate Process'
)
SELECT 
    DiffSec=DATEDIFF(s,CommentDate,(SELECT CommentDate FROM CTE c2 WHERE c2.ReferenceNo = CTE.ReferenceNo AND c2.RowNum=CTE.RowNum+1))
    , ReferenceNo
    , StepName
    , CommentDate
FROM CTE 
where referenceno='CHQRCL/0157/MAR/2013'
ORDER BY ReferenceNo, RowNum;

Comment: which gives the following output

Comment: DiffSec ReferenceNo StepName CommentDate
37 CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB Initiate Process 2013-02-25 15:20:07.000
68 CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB Finance Controller 2013-02-25 15:20:44.000
94 CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB Originator 2013-02-25 15:21:52.000
29 CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB Finance Controller 2013-02-25 15:23:26.000
NULL CHQRCL/0083/2013/FEB Finance Officer 2013-02-25 15:23:55.000

Comment: where Initiate Process is taknig 37 seconds whereas Initiate Process should be NULL / 0 and this 37 seconds should be for next step i.e., 'Finance Controller'

Comment: @JamieF The time difference calculation is happening correctly but for wrong step name.

Comment: @JamieF I used the following query which resolved my issue, 

WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ReferenceNo ORDER BY CommentDate)As RowNum, *
  FROM  FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory T
)
SELECT ReferenceNo, StepName, CommentDate, DiffDays = DATEDIFF(s, (SELECT CommentDate FROM CTE c2 WHERE c2.ReferenceNo = CTE.ReferenceNo AND c2.RowNum=CTE.RowNum-1), CommentDate)  / 60.0 / 60.0 / 24.0
FROM CTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following query which resolved my issue, 
WITH CTE AS( 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ReferenceNo ORDER BY CommentDate)As RowNum, * 
FROM FNCUSTOM.dbo.WorkflowHistory T 
)
 SELECT ReferenceNo, StepName, CommentDate, DiffDays = DATEDIFF(s, (SELECT CommentDate FROM CTE c2 WHERE c2.ReferenceNo = CTE.ReferenceNo AND c2.RowNum=CTE.RowNum-1), CommentDate) / 60.0 / 60.0 / 24.0 
FROM CTE